# Selenium browser c# click

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to pick value in the dropdown on form.

Current HTML looks like

```
<div class="listing-editor__input--half d--ib va--t">
   <div aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" class="dropdown form__text--select d--b dropdown--expanded" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="dropdown__selector dropdown__selector--select-tag dropdown__selector--select-tag--large">
         <p data-et-name="category" class="tc--lg">
            Select Subcategory (optional)
         </p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <ul class="dropdown__menu">
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Belts</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Glasses</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Gloves &amp; Mittens</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Hair Accessories</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Hats</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Hosiery &amp; Socks</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Key &amp; Card Holders</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Laptop Cases</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Phone Cases</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Scarves &amp; Wraps</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Sunglasses</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Tablet Cases</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Umbrellas</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">Watches</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown__menu__item"><a class="dropdown__link">None</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="form__error-message" style="display: none;">
   </p>
</div>
```

And im trying to pick by string "Phone"

Tried with

```
    // select the drop down list
    var education = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#content > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > section:nth-child(4) > div > div.col-x24.col-l20 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.dropdown__selector.dropdown__selector--select-tag.dropdown__selector--select-tag--large");

    //create select element object 
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(education);

    // select by text
    selectElement.SelectByText("Phone");
```

Output

> OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException: 'Element should have been select but was div'

[image: Selector pick]

Edit>

[image]

Comment: do you have a `<select>` element in your html?because in your screenshot you are copying the selector from a `div`, you will need to select the text in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectElement` can be used only with HTML [select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). Steps to select the dropdown in HTML you provided:

1. click on dropdown to expand it
2. find and click on "option" element.

```
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://poshmark.com/create-listing");

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_form_username_email")).SendKeys("username");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_form_password")).SendKeys("password");
        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[data-vv-name='title']"))).SendKeys("Title controled by t3cho");

        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-vv-name='originalPrice']")).SendKeys("22");

        var categoryCombobox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-et-name='category']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'isting-editor__input--half')][1]"));
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false)", categoryCombobox);
        categoryCombobox.Click();

        var category1 = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Accessories"));
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false)", category1);
        category1.Click();

        var category2 = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Glasses"));
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false)", category2);
        category2.Click();
    }
```

Download `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` NuGet Package for `ExpectedConditions`.

Comment: Can you please take a look on updated picture . I don't have "option" element

Comment: Try code in the answer. Check in Dev Tools if `div.listing-editor__input--half` is unique or provide URL if possible.

Comment: pastebin of source page : https://pastebin.com/HcEy6m3Z 
website is https://poshmark.com/create-listing your answer is throwing type error  'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'FindElementByLinkText'

Comment: Code should be `FindElement(By.linkText("Phone"))`

Comment: it says OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@data-et-name='category']/.."}

Comment: The website load content dynamically, you have to use WebDriverWait.

Comment: Other elements such as areas and input boxes are working well. Everything beside this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206471/discussion-between-sers-and-programer-anel).

Comment: Unfortunanetly still getting the exception `OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=element click intercepted: Element <div class="listing-editor__input--half d--ib va--t">...</div> is not clickable at point (346, 24). Other element would receive the click: <div class="header__con d--fl jc--sb">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown__menu']"))).SelectByText("Phone Cases");
```